# Error When Connecting to Azure from PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell

I connect to Azure using Powershell.

I am able to connect once or twice with below command, but in 3rd attempt i gives me error.

I have tried clear-azcontext, disconnect-azaccount. But still the error comes in 3rd or 4th attempt of running below command.

Command

```
Connect-AzAccount -Subscription ***-***-Tenant ***-*** -Environment ***-Credential $Credential
```

ERROR:

```
Connect-AzAccount : An error occurred while sending the request

At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-AzAccount -Subscription ***-*** -Tenant ***-***...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzAccount], HttpRequestException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand
```

Comment: Try to run your powershell as admin, update the module with `Update-Module -Name Az`, then login again.

Comment: Is my comment above helpful?

Comment: Yes It is .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

powershell cmdlets, sometimes it couldn't give a proper error message. So to resolve the issue , you can try to re-install or update the concerned module.

Alternatively you can try to use **`$DebugPreference= "Continue"`** before executing the **`Connect-AzAccount`**

It determines how PowerShell responds to debugging messages generated by a script, cmdlet or provider, or by a Write-Debug command at the command line.

Some cmdlets display debugging messages, which are typically very technical messages designed for programmers and technical support professionals. By default, debugging messages are not displayed, but you can display debugging messages by changing the value of $DebugPreference.

You can read more about **`$DebugPreference`** [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-6#debugpreference).
Sample output for the same:

```
PS> $ErrorView                         # Verify the value.
NormalView

PS> Get-ChildItem nofile.txt           # Find a non-existent file.
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\nofile.txt' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:14
+ Get-ChildItem  <<<< nofile.txt



Status Code:
NotFound

Headers:
Pragma                        : no-cache
x-ms-failure-cause            : gateway
x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-writes: 1199
x-ms-request-id               : 65972d3e-495e-41fd-84fd-9b068c62df22
x-ms-correlation-request-id   : 65972d3e-xx-41fd-84fd-xx
x-ms-routing-request-id       : xxx:xxx:65972d3e-xx-41fd-84fd-xx
Strict-Transport-Security     : max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options        : nosniff
Cache-Control                 : no-cache
Date                          : Tue, 04 Sep 2018 02:45:49 GMT

Body:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceGroupNotFound",
    "message": "Resource group 'test' could not be found."
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the below first from Powershell

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Then run connect-az command again to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your powershell as admin, update the module with `Update-Module -Name Az`, then login again. Then it will work fine.